# CSS3 curved shadow appears infront of tile when tile is rotated or is assigned a z-index

Tags: css

Was wondering if you could help me solve an issue I'm having with the shadow on my tile, the shadow sits behind the tile in position fine until I add rotate or z-index to the tile `.tile` can anyone advise me on how to solve this problem?

**SCSS**

```
body {
  background: lightBlue;
}

.tile {
  background: white;
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 6;
  @include transform(rotate(15.5deg));

  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: '';
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    max-width: 300px;
    @include box-shadow(0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
  }

  &::before {
    left: 10px;
    @include transform(rotate(-3deg));
  }

  &::after {
    right: 10px;
    @include transform(rotate(3deg));
  }
}
```

**Codepen**: http://codepen.io/styler/pen/bmozr

Comment: Can you explain, perhaps with an image, the problem you're getting? They appear the same whether or not it's rotated to me

Comment: the issue is to do with the stacking order of the parent afaik when applying a z-index http://forrst.com/posts/z_index_on_pseudo_elements_of_CSS_transformed_el-PK5

Comment: I realize it's a stacking issue if it is an issue. It's unclear to me what effect you want though

Comment: I want to rotate the tile and have the shadow behind it, comment out the z-index and rotate and youll see the effect, I want that but at rotate(15.5), z-index will be used with multiple tiles stacked

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/ - This achieves the effect using an additional inner element

Answer (score 2):

You can solve that in modern browsers, at least, enabling 3d space (z-index won't work).

SCSS

```
.tile {
  background: white;
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 6;
  @include transform(rotate(15.5deg));
  @include transform-style(preserve-3d);    // added

  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: '';
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    max-width: 300px;
    @include box-shadow(0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
  @include transform-style(preserve-3d);          // added
  }

  &::before {
    left: 10px;
    @include transform(rotate(-3deg) translateZ(-10px));    // moved in z
  }

  &::after {
    right: 10px;
    @include transform(rotate(3deg) translateZ(-10px));    // moved in z
  }
```

### [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdqFa)

I have pushed the shadows behind the main div.

Since IE won't support preserve 3d, that is a little bit useless, but it's not my fault :-)

An alternate way would be to generate the shadow with linear-gradients backgrounds. This is a little bit less realistic, but will work ok in IE:

CSS

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(-5deg, transparent 15px, gray 25px), linear-gradient(5deg, transparent 15px, gray 25px);
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    background-position: 6% 0%, 94% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/k9MKH/)

Comment: @ZachSaucier Sorry about that :-)